# Can't sign in to google play after I updated my code

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am trying to understand some basıics of real time multiplayer games on andoid so I followed [this](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart#before_you_begin) guide and set up the buttonCliker2000 app. The app used to work flawless but when I added some logs into the app just to have a better understanding of things I started to get this error

```
05-08 16:12:53.841: W/GameHelper(11731): **** APP NOT CORRECTLY CONFIGURED TO USE GOOGLE PLAY GAME SERVICES
05-08 16:12:53.841: W/GameHelper(11731): **** This is usually caused by one of these reasons:
05-08 16:12:53.841: W/GameHelper(11731): **** (1) Your package name and certificate fingerprint do not match
05-08 16:12:53.841: W/GameHelper(11731): ****     the client ID you registered in Developer Console.
05-08 16:12:53.841: W/GameHelper(11731): **** (2) Your App ID was incorrectly entered.
05-08 16:12:53.841: W/GameHelper(11731): **** (3) Your game settings have not been published and you are 
05-08 16:12:53.841: W/GameHelper(11731): ****     trying to log in with an account that is not listed as
                                                 (gives my information which is correct!)
```

After this log it tells me to check google plays [troubleshoot page](http://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting) I checked it and everything seems okay.

Can Anyone help me?

Comment: Ae u using same keystore after updating ur code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea how i solved this problem but after a couple of reinstalls it started working !!!